# C : Incorrect sizeof calculation of nested structure

Tags: c, nested, structure, pack

I have issue with calculating size of nested structures in C.
I am using attribute pack to not allow padding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint32_t x;            // 4bytes
    uint32_t y;            // 4bytes
} bar_t;                  // total 8bytes

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint8_t a;               // 1bytes
    uint16_t b;              // 2bytes
    uint8_t c;               // 1bytes
    uint8_t d;               // 1bytes
    uint8_t e;               // 1bytes
    uint8_t f;               // 1bytes
    uint8_t g;               // 1bytes
    uint32_t h;              // 4bytes
    bar_t bar[0];            // 8bytes
} foo_t;                 //total 20bytes = 0x14

int main() {
    foo_t *foo = malloc(sizeof(foo_t));
    printf("sizeof foo 0x%lX  sizeof foo_t 0x%lX  sizeof bar_t 0x%lX\n", \
            sizeof(foo), sizeof(foo_t), sizeof(bar_t));
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sizeof foo 0x8  sizeof foo_t 0xC  sizeof bar_t 0x8
```

I expect result to be

```
sizeof foo 0x14  sizeof foo_t 0x14  sizeof bar_t 0x8
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: the output you received is correct.  this expression: `sizeof(foo)` is asking for the size of a pointer, Not what the pointer points at. Note: `sizeof()` is a compile time operator, not a run time operator.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  using `gcc -c -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on ubuntu linux 16.04 causes the compiler to output: *filename.c:19:11: warning: ISO C forbids zero-size array 'bar' [-Wpedantic]*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zero length array doesn't take up any space. It's effectively just a pointer to the end of the object. You have to allocate extra space if you have more than zero entries.

And `foo` is a pointer. I don't know why you'd expect a pointer to be 20 bytes, but pointers are clearly 8 bytes on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a pointer it takes up only 4 bytes(32-bit) and 8 bytes(64-bit)(btw This is your case since you are using a 64 bit architecture). Because it only need to store the address of some variable no matter how big that variable is.